# Spring context initialisation hangs when executing a test annotated with @SpringBootTest after a test annotated with @DataJpaTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I think I've stumbled about a bug in either Spring, Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA or Spring Data ReST. When I execute a test annotated with `@DataJpaTest` before a test annotated with `@SpringBootTest` the initialisation of the application context of the Spring Boot test hangs. Unfortunately the minimal example to reproduce the issue is too large to be posted here, so have uploaded an example project reproducing the issue [here](https://github.com/zustse/spring-boot-hanging-test-issue).

I have the following questions

- Is it a bug or is it a strange setup?
- Is the bug already known? (I have been looking for error problems in GitHub and StackOverflow, but found nothing that fits)
- If it is a bug in which project Spring Framework, Spring Boot, Spring Data Jpa or Spring Data ReST should I open a bug issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I doubt it is a bug in either of those frameworks but rather an issue with your code and how you structured things. One thing I notice is that you have an `@EnableAsync` on your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation classes. Generally you want hat to be on a different `@Configiuration` class so that `@DataJpaTest` can only load that what it needs (JPA, datasource etc.) now it does more due to that annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Usually I use a separate configuration class with `@EnableAsync` but for this example I didn't matter so I waived it. Do you have a guess which of the 4 framework parts is most likely the cause of the error? From what I have seen, the most likely candidate is Spring Data ReST.

Comment: There is no error. If I remove the `@EnableAsync` everything works.

Comment: Ok you have found another workaround, but disabling async is not possible for us because the action `WorkspaceLifecycleManager#onWorkspaceCreated(...)` that is triggered by the `WorkspaceCreatedEvent` is a long running background operation we want to execute asynchronously. But maybe I made a mistake previously, because if I move the `@EnabelAsync` into a separate config then the setup works fine contrary to my statement above. This is perhaps the most convenient workaround or even the solution.

Comment: That is the solution as when using sliced tests the `@Configuration` classes are ignored as to only bootstrap what is needed. When that isn't the case and everything is put on the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated classes those things cannot be excluded. Although the fact that switching the order might indicate a small race condition somewhere (judging from the logging output I suspect in the bootstrapping of JPA which is delayed and suddenly happening on a different thread).